# Media gallery images url instead of ID on WP API

Tags: rest-api

I'm getting this in my json response

```
"Gallery Images": [
    "1833",
    "1834",
    "1835"
],
```

Those are the ID's of my custom post gallery , I need to get the URL of each ID. I did't find any solution, all images com from custom filed. My field it's called  "_job_gallery_images"

Any help will be very appreciated.

Seems like I wasn't even modifying my json response because of a plugin I had activated, turning it off made me declare my meta in my functions.php file and no I have this.

` add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_custom_fields', 1, 1);

```
function register_custom_fields(){

  register_rest_field(
    'job_listing',
    'gallery',
    array(
      'get_callback' => 'show_image'
    )
  );

}

function show_main_image($object, $field_name, $request){
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($object['id']);
  $main_image = $custom_fields['_job_gallery_images'];

  return $main_image;
}`
```

But still no luck, now the "_job_gallery_images" endpoint appears to be empty
i need to response all url instead of ID

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `wp_get_attachment_image_url` for getting the URL of images: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/

or `wp_get_attachment_url` for getting the URL for attachments other than images: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/.

These functions return the URLs only and you could use them like so:

```
// your JSON
$json = '
    {
        "Gallery Images": [
            "1833",
            "1834",
            "1835"
        ]
    }
';

// convert it to PHP array
$array = get_object_vars( json_decode( $json ) );

// loop through array and get the image URLs
foreach ( $array['Gallery Images'] as $id ) {
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $id );
}
```

You could also retrieve more than just the URL, `wp_get_attachment_image_src` for example returns width and height of the image file as well: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/.

Comment: Sorry not getting and also not work. can you please write full function